# Baseline classification accuracy with Mahout

Tags: machine-learning, mahout

In his [Data Mining with Weka](https://weka.waikato.ac.nz/dataminingwithweka/preview) class, Prof. Witten stresses the importance of checking your classifier against simpler ones, like the ZeroR classifier which picks the most common class (if your fancy machine learning algorithm is barely beating ZeroR's accuracy, it's probably not working very well).

Is there a way to check baseline accuracy of a classifier built with Apache Mahout, either using ZeroR or some thing else?

Answer (score 0):

Take your data, count how often the classes occur.

And that's literally what ZeroR does. Since it is so simple I don't think Mahout includes it in their Framework.

**Writing a MapReduce job to do this is rather simple:**

Mapper:

- emit the class as key, 1 as value (let the mapper precompute the sum over his whole input for network efficiency or use a combiner)

Reducer

- sum over all keys, take the max and divide by the sum over all classes

Then you would know what baseline accuracy you would get from predicting the majority class.

**The Spark implementation is similar:**

Group by the class and then count per class and divide by the sum over all classes. Pick the max, that's the baseline.